# python sum function is giving error when summing user input

Tags: python, sum

```
print ("Budget Analysis Program")
print()
budget = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for the month: $"))
print()
print("<<<<Your Expenses for the month>>>>")
amount = float(input("Enter an amount spent (0 to quit): $"))
#calculate the amount left in budget
while (amount>0):
      amount = float(input("Enter an amount spent (0 to quit): $"))
while (amount<0):
      amount = float(input("Enter an amount spent (0 to quit): $"))
print()
sum =0
total = sum(amount)
print("Budgeted: $", budget)
print("   Spent: $", total)
print()
def left(float):
 left = (budget - total)
if (left > 0):
 print ("You are $",left,"under budget. WELL DONE!")
elif (left == 0):
   print ("Spending matches budget. Good Planning!")
else:
   print ("You are $",abs (left),"over budget. PLAN BETTER NEXT TIME!")
```

Here is the program I am writing, but I am getting an error saying that "function" can't be combined with "float" or something of that sort. The error is with my sum command, can someone help guide me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Line 13 (`sum=0`) defines a variable called `sum` -- after that point you've lost the `sum` function -- it's now an `int` -- and explains the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Comment: Well, yeah. You have a variable `sum`, and then you attempt to call the function `sum` that you have _just_ overridden. What did you expect?

Comment: Note that you do the same thing with `float` on line 18, although it doesn't cause an issue as you don't attempt to use the `float` function inside your `left` function.